# "enable google sync" stays unchecked after saving/reloading

Tags: google-apps

Does anybody know how to activate the google mobile sync in standard edition?
Every time i try to save the checked "enable google sync" checkbox, the checkbox is unchecked again after reloading...

Is there another way for doing this? I cant use my calendar, contacts, email on my iphone - very nasty!!!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this relates to google-app-engine, so i removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that google knows about. See this [discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=331a71bd3642e425&hl=en). Hopefully it will be fixed this week or next.